# Can I use different skrollr anchor values depending on the width of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I am having difficulty making my desired [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) animation occur exactly the way I want it to across different screen widths. I use media queries in my external stylesheet to adjust the layout of my page, and I need to have a different absolute value anchor for each width: desktop, tablet, and mobile.

I have searched online and through the [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) documentation and haven't seen anything that will help me.

To be more clear, 'data-2415-start' works great in desktop, but because the view changes size in tablet, 2415 isn't the value I want for that width.

What can I do to achieve this level of precision across the different sizes?

UPDATE: Attempting to follow comment below

Am I on the right track with this?

```
<div data-_startAnchor-start = "top:0px;" data-2610-start = "top:-140px"></div>

skrollr.init({
    constants: {
        startAnchor: function() {

            var width = screen.width;
            var startAnchor;

            if (width > 800) {
                startAnchor = 2415;
            } else if (width > 600) {
                startAnchor = 2215;
            } else if (width > 400) {
                startAnchor = 2115;
            }

            return startAnchor;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Use ["dynamic constants"](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#dynamic-constants) to replace `2415` with a variable.

Comment: @Prinzhorn thanks so much for your response, I don't know how I missed that. I edited my post above to reflect my attempt to use dynamic constants, am I on the right path? It isn't working quite right so there must be something I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in HTML are case **insensitive**, which means you can't use upper case constants either. Apart from that, you did everything right (you should also handle < 400 though, instead of returning `undefined`).

```
<div data-_startanchor-start = "top:0px;" data-2610-start = "top:-140px"></div>

skrollr.init({
    constants: {
        startanchor: function() {

            var width = screen.width;
            var startAnchor;

            if (width > 800) {
                startAnchor = 2415;
            } else if (width > 600) {
                startAnchor = 2215;
            } else if (width > 400) {
                startAnchor = 2115;
            }

            return startAnchor;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The animation kind of works once now, but when you scroll back down it doesn't animate anymore. It just does it once. Is that an issue related to what I am trying to do with these dynamic constants?